# Always execute index.php in root directory rather than subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file in my root directory, /

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [NC,QSA]
```

No matter the directory, /test1, /test2 apache will execute index.php with the server variables and the PHP code will display the application as needed.

I have an unrelated folder, classes, storing PHP classes. I want to make /classes be a page on this application using the above logic, however using the current .htaccess tries to execute index.php inside the /classes folder

How can I make the current mod rewrite code ALWAYS execute index.php in the root directory?

Comment: You want `/index.php`, not `index.php`. That is the difference between an _absolute_ and a _relative_ path.

Comment: `index.php` or `/index.php` - no difference sadly. I too thought `/index.php` would work!

Comment: 1. make sure that you are not looking at cached results. If that is not the issue here, then 2. please add the specific requests you are working with to the question and sketch your file system layout.